# NotFoundException - in splash screen for android 10

Tags: android, xml

> **First of all, it works well on many phones,**

I'm getting crash in friebase crash anayltics

[image]

I don't know why this happens

my code for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bookit_green"
    android:layoutDirection="locale"
    tools:activity=".activity.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/bookit_sp_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

code for my activity that shows how i implement my splash screen

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent mainIntent;
            if (LoginPreference.getLogInState(this))
                mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            else
                mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

device specifications has crash
[image]

Comment: Please share your activity class

Comment: question is updated now

Comment: you missed the resource `android:src="@drawable/bookit_sp_logo"`. Please put the resource in res->drawable folder

Comment: no it's there in it's all sizes

Comment: Plz put in res->drawable too. It will take for default case

Comment: please check this image https://prnt.sc/tmn296